# MongoDB query for getting the count of the values along with respective key names

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have created a pipeline between 3 collections and the final result must be in count based on their respective field. Hope someone gives some assistance.

INPUT

```
{
    "_id" : "josh_7@user.com",
    "users" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("612f60cb5dce270014648294"),
            "userType" : "Admin",
            "userPlan" : "GROWTH",
            "username" : "josh_7@user.com",
            "company" : "josh_7@user.com",
            "accounts" : [
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "username" : "josh_7@user.com"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "username" : "josh_7@user.com",
                        "status" : "ERROR"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "username" : "josh_7@user.com",
                        "status" : "SENT"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "username" : "josh_7@user.com",
                        "status" : "REMOVED_FROM_QUEUE"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "username" : "josh_7@user.com",
                        "status" : "REMOVED_FOR_PUBLISH"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "username" : "josh_7@user.com",
                        "status" : "UNSCHEDULED"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
       
    ]
}
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
{
            "_id": "josh_7@user.com",
            "users": [
                {
                    "username": "josh_7@user.com",
                    "userType": "Admin",
                    "userPlan": "GROWTH",
                    "company": "josh_7@user.com",
                    "accounts": [  // This section is where i got stuck
                        {
                            "_id": "josh_7@user.com,
                            "READY_TO_GO_count": 0,
                            "SENT": 36,
                            "UNSCHEDULED": 0,
                            "AWAITING_APPROVAL": 0,
                            "REMOVED_FROM_QUEUE": 16,
                            "FLAGGED": 1,
                            "ERROR": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

I tried using the below line

```
{$group:{_id:"$status",count:{$sum:1}}}
```

The output was :

```
"accounts" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "SENT",
                    "count" : 4.0
                },
                {
                    "_id" : "REMOVED_FROM_QUEUE",
                    "count" : 8.0
                }
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I Figured something for the above question, If it's not the best way, Please do correct me.

```js
{$group:{_id:"$username","SENT":{$sum:{$cond:[{$eq:["$status","SENT"]},1,0]}},"AWAITING_APPROVAL":{$sum:{$cond:[{$eq:["$status","AWAITING_APPROVAL"]},1,0]}},"FLAGGED":{$sum:{$cond:[{$eq:["$status","FLAGGED"]},1,0]}},}}
```

Result

```js
{
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ed7abc5986c050012d4aa4a"),
            "userType" : "Regular",
            "userPlan" : "GRANDE",
            "username" : "shan2@psk3n.com",
            "company" : "tariyi8792@psk3n.com",
            "accounts" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "shan2@psk3n.com",
                    "SENT" : 1.0,
                    "AWAITING_APPROVAL" : 0.0,
                    "FLAGGED" : 0.0
                }
            ]
        }
```